# Is it really possible to earn all those badges at once?

Tags: support, badges

I was looking at the Badges page, where there's the Recent Badges listing on the right side column, which took me attention when I saw an expressive amount of badge earning by the same user.

For example, [42 popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=510360), [29 notable question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/27/notable-question?userid=510360), and [8 famous question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question?userid=510360).

I've investigated the situation to try to understand what happened, but I couldn't find any suspicious pattern in his posts, which makes me guess it's actually due to some kind of curious workflow on Stack Overflow that generates this behavior by design.

What happened?

Comment: Those badges are not awarded when the question hits the required number of views and are done in batches.  Most likely they where just able to get their questions shared in an area with a large audience such as redit.

Comment: The scripts that award the badges run at different intervals to avoid overhead. I imagine it has something to do with that.

Comment: Is it because of account merger or stuff like that? Some questions are years old with nearly 100k views.

Comment: Well, it *looks* suspicious. But we cannot say, this one is for mods or SE to look at.

Comment: the simple fact that some of these posts have well in excess of the required views for those badges, I'd say @BhargavRao probably has it correct - something triggered an account merger, so the badges that were previously awarded to an other account were awarded to this account.  If all of the posts had very close to the required number of views for the badge, then I'd consider it could be more suspicious

Comment: Member for 5 years and was awarded yearling 4 minutes ago, 4 times

Comment: @user193661 that smells like an account merger for sure.

Comment: Actually I am more interested in the fact that this user has no tags with score > 1... but still has posts from 2010 (e.g. the best answer) with 90+ upvotes... how? D:

Comment: @MarcoBonelli the tag scores are only calculated once daily. The script hasn't run yet since the account merge.

Comment: @MartinSmith oh yeah.. forgot about the account merge... lol

Comment: If this isn't an account merger, then there's something odd happening. Check out the deleted answer here (10k users) along with the non-deleted one http://stackoverflow.com/a/34094086/1663001

Comment: @DavidG Not related at all, but what are all these crap answers on the question you've just linked? Why so many not-Java answers?

Comment: @Blackhole That's what you get when you start with a terrible question I guess. I've voted to close it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This was the result of an account merger. Another account was merged into this one.

On merger, questions are moved from the old, now deleted account to the target account, but badges are not. Instead, the system re-awards badges to the new account.

Comment: Ah my thoughts were correct. :-). How does one request for account merger?

Comment: @BhargavRao, they mostly seem to happen to people who don't want them >:(

Comment: @BhargavRao: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts; use the contact form. There is also an automatic merge process that kicks in when two accounts have the same email address, but there are various other criteria to that process (like reputation checks) that are not all that public and I am not familiar with the process.